DP out to usb-c to hdmi. Is that possible?
I want to connect my desktop computer to the TV through a hole in the wall which should be as small as possible. The two devices are only couple of centimeters away from each other, so cable length should not matter.
My first idea was to connect the PC via an HDMI-to-USB-C cable and then go back to HDMI again. Problem is that I could not find an HDMI-to-USB-C cable that transports the signal comming from HDMI to USB-C but just the other way round.
So I've come up with the idea to use a DisplayPort-to-USB-C cable which is supposed to be biderectional, plug the DP end to the PC, connect the USB-C end via an USB-C coupler tho the USB-C-to-HDMI cable and plug the HDMI end to the TV.
I've got a HDMI to USB-C cable which works totally fine if I connect a laptop to my TV for instance. Same with the DP-to-USB-C cable (of course in the "wrong" direction). What I cannot test in my setup is the USB-C coupler and weather the DP-to-USB-C cable really is bidirectional.
My question now is if this setup, in theory, is possible in the first place?

Maybe check out Micro HDMI, it’s a very small connector.

I thought so, too, but cannot find an adapter from micro hdmi to normal hdmi

Such adapters are by the ton at Aliexpress, Amazon, etc.

There is also mini displayport, which is about the same size as usb-c and may be a bit easier to find adapters for

@smoff googling hdmi to micro adaptor gives a shedload of assorted types. Notably this sort of thing could easily be combined with a micro hdmi to full hdmi cable to get a smaller connector through the wall.

The smallest I can think of is DP to Ethernet to DP because you can crimp an ethernet cable yourself, so you could effectively create the cable you need.

Your questions all derive from a goofy requirement, i.e. "a hole in the wall which should be as small as possible". Such a hole in the wall will look like a kludge that it is. Instead use a wall plate over a single-gang box.

https://images.monoprice.com/productlargeimages/125731.jpg?_gl=1hte4bi_gaNDk4NjU1Nzc4LjE3MTMyMzgyNjc._ga_CRFDN7FZH7*MTcxMzIzODI2Ni4xLjEuMTcxMzIzODMwNi4yMC4wLjA.
